# Put duplicated code in method C#

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Tst001
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      int[,] showArray = new int[20, 20];
      string[,] Walk = new string[20, 20];
      int a = 0;
      int b = 0;
      int leftCount = 0;
      int rightCount = 0;
      double leftOver = 0;
      double moveCommand;
      int countLeft = 0;
      int countRight = 0;
      int m = 0;
      int n = 0;

      for (int x = 0; x < showArray.GetLength(0); x++)//Determine all values to be 0s
      {
         for(int y = 0; y < showArray.GetLength(1); y++)
         {
            showArray[x, y] = 0;
         }
      }

      DisplayCommand();

      do 
      {
         Console.Write("Enter command: ");
         moveCommand = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

         if (moveCommand == 3 || moveCommand == 4)//Use these values to determine the directions
         {
            if (moveCommand == 3)
            {
               rightCount++;
               countRight = rightCount % 4;
            }
            else
            {
               leftCount++;
               countLeft = leftCount % 4;
            }
         }
         else if ((int)moveCommand == 5)//Determines the limit of how many passes can be made and eventually passes that walked
         {
            leftOver = moveCommand * 100;
            leftOver = (int)leftOver;
            leftOver -= 500;
            leftOver -= 1;

            if (leftOver >= 20)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Exceed limit of array!");
            }
            else if (leftOver < 20)
            {
               if (Directions(countLeft, countRight) == "-V")
               {
                  if (a - (int)leftOver >= 0)
                  {
                     a -= (int)leftOver;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     Console.WriteLine("Exceed limit of array! Do not enter more than {0} passes!", a);
                  }
               }
               else if (Directions(countLeft, countRight) == "V")
               {
                  if (a + (int)leftOver < 20)
                  {
                     a += (int)leftOver;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     Console.WriteLine("Exceed limit of array! Do not enter more than {0} passes!", (19 - a));
                  }
               }
               else if (Directions(countLeft, countRight) == "-H")
               {
                  if (b - (int)leftOver >= 0)
                  {
                     b -= (int)leftOver;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     Console.WriteLine("Exceed limit of array! Do not enter more than {0} passes!", b);
                  }
               }
               else
               {
                  if (b + (int)leftOver < 20)
                  {
                     b += (int)leftOver;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     Console.WriteLine("Exceed limit of array! Do not enter more than {0} passes!", (19 - b));
                  }
               }
            }                
         }
         else if (moveCommand == 6)//command 6 shows the walked
         {
            for (int x = 0; x < Walk.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
               for (int y = 0; y < Walk.GetLength(1); y++)
               {
                  if (showArray[x, y] == 0)
                  {
                     Console.Write(" ");
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     Console.Write("*");
                  }
               }
               Console.WriteLine();
            }
         }
         else if (moveCommand == 2)
         {
            continue;
         }
         else if (moveCommand == 1)//Determine whether the path is walked or not
         {
            do
            {
               Console.Write("Enter command: ");
               moveCommand = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

               if (moveCommand == 3 || moveCommand == 4)//Determine the directions
               {
                  if (moveCommand == 3)
                  {
                     rightCount++;
                     countRight = rightCount % 4;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     leftCount++;
                     countLeft = leftCount % 4;
                  }
               }
               else if ((int)moveCommand == 5)// Determine the limit whether the entered value can be walked
               {
                  m = a;
                  n = b;

                  leftOver = moveCommand * 100;
                  leftOver = (int)leftOver;
                  leftOver -= 500;
                  leftOver -= 1;
                  if (leftOver>= 20)
                  {
                     Console.WriteLine("Exceed limit of array!");
                  }
                  else if (leftOver< 20)
                  {
                     if (Directions(countLeft, countRight) == "-V")
                     {
                        if (a - (int)leftOver >= 0)
                        {
                           m = a - (int)leftOver;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           Console.WriteLine("Exceed limit of array! Do not enter more than {0} passes!", a);
                        }
                     }
                     else if (Directions(countLeft, countRight) == "V")
                     {
                        if (a + (int)leftOver < 20)
                        {
                           m = a + (int)leftOver;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           Console.WriteLine("Exceed limit of array! Do not enter more than {0} passes!", (19 - a));
                        }
                     }
                     else if (Directions(countLeft, countRight) == "-H")
                     {
                        if (b - (int)leftOver >= 0)
                        {
                           n = b - (int)leftOver;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           Console.WriteLine("Exceed limit of array! Do not enter more than {0} passes!", b);
                        }
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        if (b + (int)leftOver < 20)
                        {
                           n = b + (int)leftOver;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           Console.WriteLine("Exceed limit of array! Do not enter more than {0} passes!", (19 - b));
                        }
                     }

                     //START HERE!!
                     for (int x = 0; x < showArray.GetLength(0); x++) //Determine path, where 1 is walked, 0 not walked
                     {
                        for (int y = 0; y < showArray.GetLength(1); y++)
                        {
                           if (a > m)
                           {
                              if (x >= m && x <= a && y == n)
                              {
                                 showArray[x, y] = 1;
                              }
                           }
                           else if (a < m)
                           {
                              if (x >= a && x <= m && y == n)
                              {
                                 showArray[x, y] = 1;
                              }
                           }
                           else if (b > n)
                           {
                              if (y >= n && y <= b && x == m)
                              {
                                 showArray[x, y] = 1;
                              }
                           }
                           else
                           {
                              if (y >= b && y <= n && x == m)
                              {
                                 showArray[x, y] = 1;
                              }
                           }

                        }
                     }
                     //Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", a, b, m, n);
                  }                     

                  a = m;
                  b = n;
               //END HERE!!
               }
               else if (moveCommand == 6) //command 6 shows the walked path
               {
                  for (int x = 0; x < Walk.GetLength(0); x++)
                  {
                     for (int y = 0; y < Walk.GetLength(1); y++)
                     {
                        if (showArray[x, y] == 0)
                        {
                           Console.Write(" ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           Console.Write("*");
                        }
                     }
                     Console.WriteLine();
                  }
               }
            } while (moveCommand != 2) ;
         }

         else
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong number entered!!!");
         }


         //Console.WriteLine("leftCount {0}\trightCount {1}\ta {2}\tb {3}\ncountLeft {4}\tcountRight {5}\nDirections {6}", leftCount, rightCount, a, b, countLeft, countRight, Directions(countLeft,countRight)); //Just for checking values
      } while (moveCommand != 9);

      Console.Read();
   }

   public static string Directions(int x, int y) //Determine directions, V for vertical, H for horizontal
   {
      string[,] Direction = { {"-V","H","V","-H" },
                              {"-H","-V","H","V" },
                              {"V","-H","-V","H" },
                              {"H","V","-H","-V" }};

      return Direction[x, y];
   }

   public static void DisplayCommand()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Enter 3 to move Right,\n" +
         "Enter 4 to move Left,\n" +
         "Enter 5,x to determine amount of passes\n" +
         "Enter 1 to move pencil down,\n" +
         "Enter 2 to move pencil up,\n" +
         "Enter 6 to draw the array,\n" +
         "Enter 9 to end the program!\n");
   }
}
```

Currently I am learning to code in C#. This is an exercise from a book. I managed to finish this exercise. However, I like to know whether some of the "commands" can be put into methods(not required from the book, just curious from my side). As you can see, there are quite a lot of duplicated codes. My main problem to solve this, is the fact that a few values (a, b, leftCount etc.) are used by those "commands". I don't know how to take those values when the commands are put into methods.

edit:
command 2 should be "pencil up" instead of "pencil down"
command 1 should be "pencil down" instead of "pencil up"

Comment: you could declare your fields in your class, not in the method then use it from your methods (as parameter)

Comment: You can the move the logic to another class where you can create the variables as  member variable and each method for each command condition. After that, try to identify if you code can be refactored to remove the duplicate code.

Comment: This is currently the 5th chapter of coding, I don't really understand what fields are. I will look into it. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I would isolate the code for each command into a method, and have a switch statement that called the correct command

Comment: user1672994: Are you saying making two classes? One for directions and other for the rest??

Comment: Read these first - [ask] & [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Didn't modify all the code.  It looks like you test for movecommand == 6 twice.

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Tst001
{
    static int[,] showArray = new int[20, 20];
    static int countLeft = 0;
    static int countRight = 0;
    static int leftCount = 0;
    static int rightCount = 0;
    static int leftOver = 0;
    static int a = 0;
    static int b = 0;

    static string[,] Walk = new string[20, 20];
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int moveCommand;

        for (int x = 0; x < showArray.GetLength(0); x++)//Determine all values to be 0s
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < showArray.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                showArray[x, y] = 0;
            }
        }

        DisplayCommand();
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Enter command: ");
            string cmd = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] cmdArray = cmd.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            moveCommand = Convert.ToInt16(cmdArray[0]);
            if (cmdArray.Count() == 2)
            {
                leftOver = Convert.ToInt16(cmdArray[1]);
            }

            switch (moveCommand)
            {
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    MoveLeftRight(moveCommand, leftOver);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    MoveLeftRight(moveCommand, leftOver);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Pass(moveCommand, leftOver);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    DrawArrow();
                    break;
                case 9:
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong number entered!!!");
                    break;
            }

            //Console.WriteLine("leftCount {0}\trightCount {1}\ta {2}\tb {3}\ncountLeft {4}\tcountRight {5}\nDirections {6}", leftCount, rightCount, a, b, countLeft, countRight, Directions(countLeft,countRight)); //Just for checking values
        } while (moveCommand != 9);

        Console.Read();
    }

    public static string Directions(int x, int y) //Determine directions, V for vertical, H for horizontal
    {
        string[,] Direction = { {"-V","H","V","-H" },
                              {"-H","-V","H","V" },
                              {"V","-H","-V","H" },
                              {"H","V","-H","-V" }};

        return Direction[x, y];
    }
    public static void MoveLeftRight(int moveCommand, int count)
    {
        if (moveCommand == 3 || moveCommand == 4)//Determine the directions
        {
            if (moveCommand == 3)
            {
                rightCount++;
                countRight = count;
            }
            else
            {
                leftCount++;
                countLeft = count;
            }
        }

    }
    public static void Pass(int moveCommand, int leftOver)
    {

        if (leftOver >= 20)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exceed limit of array!");
        }
        else if (leftOver < 20)
        {
            if (Directions(countLeft, countRight) == "-V")
            {
                if (a - (int)leftOver >= 0)
                {
                    a -= (int)leftOver;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exceed limit of array! Do not enter more than {0} passes!", a);
                }
            }
            else if (Directions(countLeft, countRight) == "V")
            {
                if (a + (int)leftOver < 20)
                {
                    a += (int)leftOver;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exceed limit of array! Do not enter more than {0} passes!", (19 - a));
                }
            }
            else if (Directions(countLeft, countRight) == "-H")
            {
                if (b - (int)leftOver >= 0)
                {
                    b -= (int)leftOver;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exceed limit of array! Do not enter more than {0} passes!", b);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (b + (int)leftOver < 20)
                {
                    b += (int)leftOver;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exceed limit of array! Do not enter more than {0} passes!", (19 - b));
                }
            }
        }

    }
    public static void DrawArrow()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < Walk.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < Walk.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                if (showArray[x, y] == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }
    public static void DisplayCommand()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 3 to move Right,\n" +
           "Enter 4 to move Left,\n" +
           "Enter 5,x to determine amount of passes\n" +
           "Enter 2 to move pencil down,\n" +
           "Enter 1 to move pencil up,\n" +
           "Enter 6 to draw the array,\n" +
           "Enter 9 to end the program!\n");
    }
}​
```